# c# calling method and then property (design class structure)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, design-patterns

```
public static class WebConfig
 {     
private static IList<SystemConfigs> sysconfkeys;
static WebConfig()
{         
    sysconfkeys = systemconfigrep.GetAllSystemConfig();
}

private static string _SMTPPort = "";
public static string SMTPPort
{
    get
    {
        return _SMTPPort = sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPPort") != null ? sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPPort").metavalue : "25";
    }
}

private static string _SMTPUsername = "";
public static string SMTPUsername
{
    get
    {
        return _SMTPUsername = sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPUsername") != null ? sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPUsername").metavalue : "";
    }
}
```

}

i am using the system level variable in the above way all over my system in my views or controllers. 
how can i design my this class in such a way that after calling a method to execute a query i straight away call some property like this.

usage: webconfig.getallsystemconfig().LogicalPath;

webconfig.getallsystemconfig().Smtpport;

Comment: I do not understand the question: how can i design my this (?) class in such a way that after calling a method *to execute a query i straight away call some property like this.*

Comment: my basic question is is this syntax possible? webconfig.getallsystemconfig().Smtpport?. i want to query the database for all the systemconfig variables and after that fetch one of the variables through some property or some enum or anything?

Comment: can i design my class in such a manner that i achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use extension methods to accomplish something like this:

```
public static class WebConfig
{
    private static IList<SystemConfigs> sysconfkeys;

    public static IList<SystemConfigs> Configs()
    {                                   
        return sysconfkeys ?? (sysconfkeys = systemconfigrep.GetAllSystemConfig());
    }

    public static string SMTPPort(this IList<SystemConfigs> configs)
    {
         return sysconfkeys.Any(e => e.metakey == "SMTPPort") ? sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPPort").metavalue : "25";
    }
}
```

You would use it like

```
WebConfig.Configs().SMTPPort();
```

if doesn't do the caching as in your example, but it should be a negligible loss anyway